# Como referirse a un div que contenga este tag? [BeautifulSoup4]

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy practicando web scrapping y quisiera saber como referirme al elemento div de la pagina que estoy scrappeando que contiene la siguiente propiedad

```
<div style="color:#000000; padding-left:55px; padding-bottom:1px; background
image:url(http://caribbeancinemas.com/VIP_bg.fw.png); 
background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position: right; min-height:127px;">
```

cuando me quiero referir a el en mi codigo no lo reconoce, mi codigo de momento es este

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('http://caribbeancinemas.com/theater/downtown-center/').read()

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, "html.parser")

style = "color:#000000; padding-left:55px; padding-bottom:1px; background
image:url(http://caribbeancinemas.com/VIP_bg.fw.png); 
background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position: right; min-height:127px;"


movies = soup.find('div', attrs={'class','column three-fourth column_column'})

titles = []
for movie in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class', 'column three-fourth'}):
    title =  movie.b.text
    print (title)

    for div in movie.find_all('div', style=style):

        print (div.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías incluir tu style en attrs. Es decir, algo así:

```
movie.find_all('div', attrs={'style': 'color:#000000; padding-left:55px; padding-bottom:1px; background-image:url(http://caribbeancinemas.com/VIP_bg.fw.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; \n     background-position: right; min-height:127px;'})
```

Prestar atención al "\n" antes del background-position debido a que hay un retorno de carro en el código HTML. Eso seguramente es el motivo de que no esté funcionando en tu caso.

Sin embargo, deberías buscar otra manera de encontrar el elemento deseado y no a través de un style tan complejo. Como por ejemplo, encontrar el segundo div hijo.